# how to reference a property from a class in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a simple Blazor application.

I have a label in my HTML portion of the .Razor page. In the @code section, I have a public class with a few properties, and I'm trying to simply display the values from my class in the labels.

Code below:

```
<label>@How To Display EmailAddressHere</label>

<label>@How To Display Body</label>

@code {

    public class EmailItems
    {
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        var emailItems = new EmailItems()
            {
                Body = "testBody",
                EmailAddress= "jdoe@gmail.com",
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a field or a property of type EmailItems and assign that instead of a var.

```
<label>@emailItem.EmailAddress </label>

<label>@emailItem.Body </label>

@code {

    EmailItems emailItem;

    public class EmailItems
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

            this.emailItem = new EmailItems()
            {
                Body = "testBody",
                EmailAddress= "jdoe@gmail.com",
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: how can something like this be used in case we don't actually assign the values until after the page has rendered. In this case there's a Null Exception since we are trying to reference the emailItem but the values have not been assigned. Basically saying, and event needs to take place before those values are assigned

Comment: You can do `EmailItems emailItem = new EmailItems();`

Comment: You can display a "Loading..." message while the item is null and then render after the values have been populated. See [Handle incomplete async actions at render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#handle-incomplete-async-actions-at-render)